# Removing data from firebase on a RecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, removechild

I am removing a list item with a PopupMenu on my RecyclerViewAdapter, but when the item is removed it stays on the Firebase.

> **This is on the onBindViewHolder on the RecyclerAdapter**

```
holder.opcionesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //creating a popup menu
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, holder.opcionesButton);
            //inflating menu from xml resource
            popup.inflate(R.menu.menu_edit);
            //adding click listener
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.edit_item:
                            //handle menu1 click
                            break;
                        case R.id.delete_item:

                            tareasList.remove(position);
                            notifyItemRemoved(position);
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Tareas eliminada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;

                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });
            //displaying the popup
            popup.show();
        }
    });
```

> And this is on the MainFragment

```
  final Query tareasQuery = mTareasDatabase.child(userId);
        tareasQuery.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                Tareas tareas = new Tareas();
                tareas.setFecha(dataSnapshot.getValue(Tareas.class).getFecha());
                tareas.setDescripcion(dataSnapshot.getValue(Tareas.class).getDescripcion());
                tareas.setLista(dataSnapshot.getValue(Tareas.class).getLista());
                tareas.setPrioridad(dataSnapshot.getValue(Tareas.class).getPrioridad());
                mTareasList.add(tareas);
                mTareasAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                String tareasId = dataSnapshot.getValue(Tareas.class).getTareasId();
                mTareasDatabase.child(userId).child(tareasId).removeValue();
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String tareasId = dataSnapshot.getValue(Tareas.class).getTareasId();
                mTareasDatabase.child(userId).child(tareasId).removeValue();

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
```

Everything is working fine, except that is not deleting it from the firebase

### **Solution**

Remove the item from the firebase and the recycler view at the same time

```
case R.id.delete_item:
                            FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                            String tareasId = tareas.getTareasId();
                            final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                            String userId = user.getUid();
                            DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Tareas")
                                    .child(userId).child(tareasId);
                            databaseReference.removeValue();

                            tareasList.remove(position);
                            notifyItemRemoved(position);
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Tareas eliminada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I solved it. I just had to add all the database references on the delete item, and remove it from the recycler view and the database at the same time

```
 case R.id.delete_item:
                            FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                            String tareasId = tareas.getTareasId();
                            final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                            String userId = user.getUid();
                            DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Tareas")
                                    .child(userId).child(tareasId);
                            databaseReference.removeValue();

                            tareasList.remove(position);
                            notifyItemRemoved(position);
                            Toast.makeText(context, "Tareas eliminada!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            break;
```

Comment: If you have a better way to do it, please post it

Answer (score 0):

this is because you are deleting from the local list only. You have to remove the value from firebase too. For deleting use code

```
firebaseRef.removeValue();
```

In your firebaseRef you have to show which value you want to delete.